# .py to.exe not opening

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-module

I tried doing a .py to .exe conversion using pyinstaller, modules i imported are numpy and maths the console window opens and then closes immediately. The console windows shows this

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "matrix.py", line 1, in 
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
[18864] Failed to execute script

......Please help :)

CODE:

```
import numpy as np
import math

add = sub = mul = z = 0

while True:
    print()
    print('Choose option for operations on matrix:')
    print('1. Addition')
    print('2. Subtraction')
    print('3. Multiplication')
    print('4. Determinant')
    print('5. Exit')
    print()

    choice = int(input('Enter your choice: '))
    print()

    if choice == 5:
        print('Successfully Terminated')
        break

    elif choice < 5:

        if choice == 1:
            r = int(input('Enter the number of rows of 1st matrix: '))
            c = int(input('Enter the number of columns of 1st matrix: '))
            a = np.zeros((r,c),dtype=int)

            for i in range(len(a)):
                for j in range(len(a[i])):
                    x = int(input('Enter the element of 1st matrix and press enter: '))
                    a[i][j] = x

            r1 = int(input('Enter the number of rows of 2nd matrix : '))
            c1 = int(input('Enter the number of columns of 2nd matrix : '))
            b = np.zeros((r1,c1),dtype=int)

            for i in range(len(b)):
                for j in range(len(b[i])):
                    x = int(input('Enter the element of 2nd matrix and press enter: '))
                    b[i][j] = x

            add = np.add(a,b)
            print()
            print('The sum of these two matrices are: ')
            print(add)

        elif choice == 2:
            r = int(input('Enter the number of rows of 1st matrix: '))
            c = int(input('Enter the number of columns of 1st matrix: '))
            a = np.zeros((r, c), dtype=int)

            for i in range(len(a)):
                for j in range(len(a[i])):
                    x = int(input('Enter the element of 1st matrix and press enter: '))
                    a[i][j] = x

            r1 = int(input('Enter the number of rows of 2nd matrix : '))
            c1 = int(input('Enter the number of columns of 2nd matrix : '))
            b = np.zeros((r1, c1), dtype=int)

            for i in range(len(b)):
                for j in range(len(b[i])):
                    x = int(input('Enter the element of 2nd matrix and press enter: '))
                    b[i][j] = x

            sub =np.subtract(a,b)
            print()
            print('The Difference of these two matrices are: ')
            print(sub)

        elif choice == 3:
            r = int(input('Enter the number of rows of 1st matrix: '))
            c = int(input('Enter the number of columns of 1st matrix: '))
            a = np.zeros((r, c), dtype=int)

            for i in range(len(a)):
                for j in range(len(a[i])):
                    x = int(input('Enter the element of 1st matrix and press enter: '))
                    a[i][j] = x

            r1 = int(input('Enter the number of rows of 2nd matrix : '))
            c1 = int(input('Enter the number of columns of 2nd matrix : '))
            b = np.zeros((r1, c1), dtype=int)

            for i in range(len(b)):
                for j in range(len(b[i])):
                    x = int(input('Enter the element of 2nd matrix and press enter: '))
                    b[i][j] = x
            if c != r1:
                print()
                print('Sorry, matrix multiplication is not defined for these matrices.')
            else:
                mul =np.matmul(a,b)
                print()
                print('The product of these two matrices are: ')
                print(mul)

        elif choice == 4:
            r = int(input('Enter the number of rows of 1st matrix: '))
            c = int(input('Enter the number of columns of 1st matrix: '))
            if r != c:
                print('It must be a square matrix')
            else:
                a = np.zeros((r, c), dtype=int)

                for i in range(len(a)):
                    for j in range(len(a[i])):
                        x = int(input('Enter the element of matrix and press enter: '))
                        a[i][j] = x
                z = np.linalg.det(a)
                print()
                if z > 0:
                    deter = math.floor(z)
                    print(f'The Determinant of the given matrix is {deter}')
                elif z < 0:
                    deter = math.ceil(z)
                    print(f'The Determinant of the given matrix is {deter}')
                elif z == 0:
                    print(f'The Determinant of the given matrix is {0}')

        else:
            print('Invalid Choice')
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you run it inside an activated virtual environment, which you have all libraries installed?

Comment: the prob ws tht i dint hv numpy installed fr my python? i used pycahrm to make the code, so ya thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these different command with pyinstaller, because i have tried your code and made an .exe file and its working.

Go to current directory where your .py file exits. Press shift button and then press right click, select open powershell window here. and then try these different command.

```
pyinstaller matrix.py --> (executable file with some other configuration file)
pyinstaller -F matrix.py --> (only executable file)
```

Comment: the prob was diff, but ill accept this as an answer, thank you